# Apply ACL to deployment bucket as resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I want to have ACL as a resource and reference the resource to any buckets, as I please.

Bellow snippet of code would apply a policy to the deployment bucket, using serverless framework and serverless-deployment-bucket plug in.

```
...............

custom:
  deploymentBucket:
    versioning: true
    policy: 
      {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
          ],
          "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
              "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
            }
          }
        }
        ]
      }
provider:
  region: eu-west-2
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  deploymentBucket:
    name: bucket-name
    serverSideEncryption: AES256

resources:
 - ${file(resources/deployment-bucket.yml)}

................
```

The code in deployment-bucket.yml looks like this

```
Resources:
  ServerlessDeploymentBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref ServerlessDeploymentBucketName -> this is the Identifier, taken from the CF template bundled by serverless framework.
      AccessControl: Private
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
```

The error An error occurred: ServerlessDeploymentBucket - bucket-name already exists.

The error is quite descriptive, so I assume I would need to find a way to apply the ACL resource to the bucket.
I have tried this and removing the BucketName key.
No success.

```
SourceArn:
        !Sub
        - 'arn:aws:s3:::${Bucket}/*'
        - { Bucket: Ref ServerlessDeploymentBucketName }
```

Update

This should solve the ACL problem

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-default-aws-resource-properties

Comment: a work around would be to do granular policies as shown in this tutorial, but I would like to know how to apply ACL as a resource to my deployment-bucket
https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/object-storage/how-to-use-object-storage-acls-and-bucket-policies/

Comment: Thanks. You can make an answer to your own question :-)

Comment: There are several ways to secure a bucket:
 - ACL Policy
 - Iam Policy
 - Bucket Policy

In this scenario I wanted to use ACL with serverless-deployment-bucket plug in.
A work arround is to use serverless-default-aws-resource-properties as the above plug in does not offer ACL functionality.

I can't  post an answer. I think I was a bad boy :D